# Subquery returned more than 1 value in C# Database Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I have this query written and it seems to be returning more than one value.  I'm unsure why this error is happening.  This is for an edit command that should update the information in the database (sql server) on edit, not create a new provider.

```
const string sql =
        @"UPDATE DoctorFacility SET PVId = @PVId, 
                                    Type = @Type,
                                    Inactive = @Inactive, 
                                    Prefix = @Prefix,
                                    First = @First,
                                    Middle = @Middle,
                                    Last = @Last,
                                    Suffix = @Suffix,
                                    OrgName = @OrgName,
                                    OrgType = @OrgType, 
                                    ListName = @ListName, 
                                    Address1 = @Address1, 
                                    Address2 = @Address2, 
                                    City = @City, 
                                    State = @State, 
                                    Zip = @Zip, 
                                    Country = @Country, 
                                    Phone1 = @Phone1, 
                                    Phone1Type = @Phone1Type, 
                                    Phone2 = @Phone2, 
                                    Phone2Type = @Phone2Type, 
                                    EmailAddress = @EmailAddress, 
                                    PlaceOfServiceMId = @PlaceOfSErviceMId, 
                                    UPIN = @Upin, 
                                    SpecialtyMId = @SpecialtyMId, 
                                    DotId = @DotId, 
                                    NPI = @NPI, 
                                    CreatedBy = @CreatedBy, 
                                    LastModifiedBy = @LastModifiedBy 
            WHERE DotId = @DotId";
     using (SqlDataAccessor dataAccessor = DataAccessorFactory.GetDataAccessor(Connection))
     {
        string user = UserNameFactory.GetUsername();
        DaParameters parameters = new DaParameters(dataAccessor);
        parameters.Add("@PVId", DateTimeHash(DateTime.Now));
        parameters.Add("@Type", (int)provider.ProviderType);
        parameters.Add("@Inactive", provider.Inactive);
        parameters.Add("@Prefix", provider.Prefix, DbType.AnsiString, 10);
        parameters.Add("@First", provider.FirstName, DbType.AnsiString, 35);
        parameters.Add("@Middle", provider.MiddleName, DbType.AnsiString, 30);
        parameters.Add("@Last", provider.LastName, DbType.AnsiString, 60);
        parameters.Add("@Suffix", provider.Suffix, DbType.AnsiString, 20);
        parameters.Add("@OrgName", provider.OrgName, DbType.AnsiString, 60);
        parameters.Add("@OrgType", provider.OrgType, DbType.AnsiString, 3);
        parameters.Add("@ListName", provider.ListName, DbType.AnsiString, 160);
        parameters.Add("@Address1", provider.Address1, DbType.AnsiString, 50);
        parameters.Add("@Address2", provider.Address2, DbType.AnsiString, 50);
        parameters.Add("@City", provider.City, DbType.AnsiString, 30);
        parameters.Add("@State", provider.State, DbType.AnsiString, 3);
        parameters.Add("@Zip", provider.Zip, DbType.AnsiString, 10);
        parameters.Add("@Country", provider.Country, DbType.AnsiString, 30);
        parameters.Add("@Phone1", provider.Phone1, DbType.AnsiString, 15);
        parameters.Add("@Phone1Type", provider.Phone1Type, DbType.AnsiString, 25);
        parameters.Add("@Phone2", provider.Phone2, DbType.AnsiString, 15);
        parameters.Add("@Phone2Type", provider.Phone2Type, DbType.AnsiString, 25);
        parameters.Add("@EmailAddress", provider.EmailAddress, DbType.AnsiString, 255);
        parameters.Add("@PlaceOfServiceMId", provider.PlaceOfServiceMID);
        parameters.Add("@UPIN", provider.UPIN, DbType.AnsiString, 50);
        parameters.Add("@SpecialtyMId", provider.SpecialtyMID);
        parameters.Add("@DotId", provider.DotID, DbType.AnsiString, 15);
        parameters.Add("@NPI", provider.NPI, DbType.AnsiString, 80);
        parameters.Add("@CreatedBy", user, DbType.AnsiString);
        parameters.Add("@LastModifiedBy", user, DbType.AnsiString);
        return dataAccessor.ExecuteIdentityInsert<Provider>(sql, parameters);
     }
  }
```

Comment: which db are you using mysql or sql-server? mysql <> sql-server

Comment: sql server is what im using

Comment: why `ExecuteIdentityInsert` ?

Comment: Try using `SqlCommand` and `ExecuteNonQuery`

Comment: I'm assuming that `SqlDataAccessor` and `DataAccessorFactory` are from some in-house data access layer. Given that, check and see if you're using the right method to execute an UPDATE. Just the name of it `ExecuteIdentityInsert` would imply you're not.

Comment: there could be a few triggers on the table. check for them..

Comment: Use a profiler trace to get the SQL that is being sent from your app, and try it in SSMS.